# Assigning separate controller files in AngularJS's UI Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-controller

I am new to AngularJS and AngularJS's UI Router. I have a basic index.html file in which I inject the views. And then I have app.js with the routes inside, a template client.html and a controller about that template called clientContoller.js I am trying to figure out how to assign to the controller of the $stateProvider.state the controller file clientController.js like for example in the code below.

```
$stateProvider.state('client', {
    url: '/client',
    templateUrl: 'client.html',
    controller: 'clientController.js',
    controllerAs: 'client'
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are supposed to assign to the `controller` key for `ui-router` is the **name** of the controller (not the filename). You then simply need to include your `clientController.js` file in your index.html. For example:

Inside index.html:

```
<script src="clientController.js"></script>
```

Inside your clientController.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('ClientCtrl', function($scope){
        // controller code
    });
```

Inside your app.js state definition:

```
.state('client', {
    url: '/client',
    templateUrl: 'client.html',
    controller: 'ClientCtrl'
});
```